# No exact matches in call to instance method 'appendInterpolation' in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this issue and I do not know how to solve it.

```
Text("\(Texts.orderCanceledText1) \(syncViewModel._order.id) \(Texts.orderCanceledText2)") // ERROR : here
```

```
struct Texts {
    static let orderCanceledText1 : LocalizedStringKey = "orderCanceledText1"
    static let orderCanceledText2 : LocalizedStringKey = "orderCanceledText2"
    static let orderCanceledText3 : LocalizedStringKey = "orderCanceledText3"
}
```

I am using Localization so that's why I am using this.

> **ERROR : "No exact matches in call to instance method 'appendInterpolation' "**

Comment: use

Texts.orderCanceledText1.description
syncViewModel._order.id.description
Texts.orderCanceledText2.description

if any of the above variables include nil or integer values

Comment: What is the type of `syncViewModel._order.id`?

Comment: @tromgy The syncViewModel._order.id works fine, the problem is on Texts variables . Is an int

Comment: @IrfanAnwar thats the error i get " Value of type 'LocalizedStringKey' has no member 'description' "

Comment: this link can help you https://swiftwithmajid.com/2019/10/16/localization-in-swiftui/

Comment: You are doing Localization wrong way in SwiftUI

Comment: @CameliaZaharia, check this answer if it helps. [Hacking with swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/swift-error-no-exact-matches-in-call-to-instance-method-appendinterpolation/10472). Try to identify which variable causes the issue. Is it `syncViewModel._order.id`? Does that have an optional value? If so, provide an alternative `\(syncViewModel._order.id) ?? "Value"` or whatever type is id, I assume is `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Irfan Anwar gave the good link. Solution is:

```
let goal: LocalizedStringKey = "goal"
let text = Text(goal)
```

Then

```
Text(goal).fontWeight(.bold) + Text("\(goal).fontWeight(.bold)
```

Answer (score 0):

What generally works for **optionals** as well as for other types that give this error is using `String(describing:)`:

```swift
struct Device: Codable {
    let token: String
}

Logger.debug("\(String(describing: Device()))")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        List(items, id:\.self)
        {
            item in
            Text("\(item.timestamp!)" )
        }
```

I was getting the same error as I was trying to print `item.timestamp`. By adding `!` to `item.timestamp!` it removed the error.  Just be careful if your unwrapping an empty value. Then use:

```
            List(items, id:\.self)
        {
            item in
            if let value = item.timestamp
            {
                Text("\(value)" )
            }
            
            
        }
```